# Forward Shibboleth Environment Variables to Tomcat via Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat, environment-variables, shibboleth

I am using Shibbolethv2.3 with Apache web server and Tomcat application server. I am using Apache as a reverse proxy using mod_proxy.so. I am not able to forward the Shibboleth environment variables from Apache to Tomcat. I am able to forward the attributes in the headers but as already mentioned in the wiki this approach is not safe.
I have tried forwarding the environment variables by the following directive :

SetEnv AJP_username ${username}

then at the Java side I can access the attribute by : request.getAttribute("username");
The strange thing here is that, I get a different value instead of the one set by Shibboleth. I get the Windows account name as a result. If I use any other attribute name, I get a null value.

I have searched a lot and have run out of options. Please guide me towards the right solution.

My setup details :

1. Shibboleth version : 2.3
2. OS : Windows XP SP3
3. Webserver : Apache 2.2
4. Application Server : Tomcat 6
5. Proxy module : mod_proxy.so

Comment: Make sure that your `attribute-map.xml` is set up correctly, sharing it might help.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are proxying through using ajp in the httpd.conf

```
ProxyPass /example ajp://example.org/example
```

And in the shibboleth2.xml in the ApplicationDefaults section we need to add

```
attributePrefix="AJP_"
```

So it looks something like

```
<ApplicationDefaults id="default" policyId="default"
    entityID="https://idp.example.org"
    REMOTE_USER="eppn persistent-id targeted-id"
    signing="false" encryption="false" attributePrefix="AJP_">
```

Check out this question on the shib mailing list:
http://groups.google.com/group/shibboleth-users/browse_thread/thread/2bdd3e272baf49a2?pli=1

Comment: Why the prefix?

Comment: Prefix seems to be needed but the attributes are available without prefix in Java.